# Playframework 2.3.0 issue with Scala IDE (Kepler)

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework, ide, playframework-2.3

Environment: Java 8, Scala 10, play 2.3.0 sbt plugin, scala ide kepler Version: 4.3.0

---

Issue: 1. Generated classes for "index.scala.html" and my own created new templates is populating properly into "/my-first-app/target/scala-2.10/classes_managed/views/html" folder
but while writing code into application controller I am not able to see these class when I tried to import classes individually instead of import views.html.* but I am not able to do that its not showing generated class I don't know why?

What I have tried:

1. windows->preference->workspace-> checked the check box "refresh using native hooks or polling" -> clicked apply
2. after every "**~run**" I used to refresh my workspace always.
3. I added output folders manually for

   - /my-first-app/target/scala-2.10/classes_managed/
   - /my-first-app/target/scala-2.10/classes

After trying all  still I am not able to import classes individually for any of xyz.scala.html file.

---

Issue 2: Getting multiple weird errors in xyz.scala.html syntax error for e.g.

Code snippet:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html) --> Error 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"/> 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

- Error:

  ```
  Multiple annotations found at this line:
           *too many arguments for constructor Object: ()Object
           *object templates is not a member of package play
           *type Template2 is not a member of package play.api.templates
           *not found: type BaseScalaTemplate
  ```

It is really annoying while development its slow downs the development speed.

Comment: Something is off if it's referencing `play.api.templates`, as that package is now `play.twirl.api`.

Comment: 1. [right clicked on project] 
 2. [opened properties] 
 3. [in left pan clicked on Play2]
 4. and removed default imports and added new import   "play.twirl.api._" 

it reduces error but still when I open my **main.scala.html** file in eclipse it shows error.

**Error :** 
   _Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - object templates is not a member of package play
 - type Template2 is not a member of package play.api.templates_    Please suggest what I am missing.

Comment: same problem here. i'm guessing the play plugin is not ready for 2.3 yet.

Answer (score 8):

Try again! 
Scala ide just got an update and at least the nightly version supports play 2.3.

The update site for eclipse kepler is
http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e38/scala211/dev/site/

In eclipse go to `project>properties>play2` and remove all the `play.api.templates` imports, those don't exist anymore.

---

ps: on a side note: 
i've started a google doc with notes on play+eclipse, feel free to add your own findings. [Play 2.3 and Eclipse](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gjH5TaQDKxbsrD4hzsMyUlHMq5LGFA0pletpdUwId7I/edit#)

Comment: This update rendered my eclipse FUBAR, `No editor descriptor for id scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaSourceFileEditor` and other errors, source files can no longer be viewed in eclipse. Presumably as the mentioned update site is for scala 2.11, not 2.10.

Comment: @matt sorry. hope you could fix it again. i got in the habit of using a custom eclipse for each "task" (ie i have an eclipe_ee i use only for tomcat work, an eclipse_java i use for normal java projects, eclipse_scala for scala projects, eclipse_android with the android/ndk extensions). one might think this is silly and unbearable, but it's much better than what competing plugins can do to your eclipse setup.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I turned this into a forced upgrade of my code to 2.11 and a new eclipse for 2.11 :) it actually went very well.

Comment: There is an ongoing discussion about this bug: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-ide-user/WFNoQ6GNw1k